# ValueRemapper in magmi doesn't work

Tags: magento, magmi

I intend to import categories into my magento from csv file. I use ValueRemapper of magmi. The Replaced Attribute is `categories`. And the New Values for categories is

`{{ ValueRemapper::use_csv('C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\var\import\category_ids.csv')->map({item.categories) }}`.

But when I run the import I get errors

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound....`

I tried to change the path to the csv file both with absolute and relative path, but it still has the same error. Could anyone give me a clue what the real problem of my setting? And any solution would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be missing } here:

```
->map({item.categories)
```

Try:

```
->map({item.categories})
```